# Excel find and count unique values in 2 dimensional array

Tags: excel-formula

I have arrays of excel data 3 cols x 300 rows - example

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNIT_TESTING | REMOTE_TEAM_AVATARS | SOCIAL_TIME |
| SOCIAL_TIME | ELIMINATE_LONG_LIVED_FEATURE_BRANCHES |  |

There will be blanks in some rows.

My goal among the 900 individual cells, find the unique values.
Once I have the values displayed I want to count how many instances there of each unique value.

In the trivial case above the result would be:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| SOCIAL_TIME | 2 |
| ELIMINATE_LONG_LIVED_FEATURE_BRANCHES | 1 |
| ... |  |

*In an ideal world I want to avoid creating a mid calc column of 900 elements*

Comment: Stack Overflow is about the facts, non related humor or salutations should not be part of the question.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: On StackOverflow - somehow this seems sad. We all need to smile a little more often. However I will abide.

Comment: On Excel Version - Office 365 MacOS - 16.55

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use UNIQUE, FILTER and SEQUENCE to get the desired output:

```
=LET(
    rng,    A1:C2,
    clm,    COLUMNS(rng),
    ct,     ROWS(rng)*clm,
    arr,    INDEX(rng,INT(SEQUENCE(ct,,1,1/clm)),MOD(SEQUENCE(ct,,0),clm)+1),
    flt,    FILTER(arr,arr<>""),
    unq,    UNIQUE(flt),
    SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},unq,COUNTIF(rng,unq)),{2,1},{-1,1}))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Irony I had spent approx an hour on this so far. I knew a few pieces and in a few minutes you managed to do the whole thing and make it readable. Hat tip.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't get further than doing it in two steps: first get the unique values with `=LET(a,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),b,FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),c,FILTER(C:C,C:C<>""),ra,ROWS(a),rb,ROWS(b),rc,ROWS(c),rabc,ra+rb+rc,unq,UNIQUE(IF(SEQUENCE(rabc)<=ra,a,IF(SEQUENCE(rabc)<=ra+rb,INDEX(b,SEQUENCE(ra+rb,,-ra+1)),INDEX(c,SEQUENCE(rabc,,-ra-rb+1))))),unq)` and then next to it have a count if reference the spill range `E1#` in my case: `=COUNTIF(A1:C3,E1#)`

Comment: I read it through more carefully and this is a briljant way to combine a range of columns into one column dynamically. If I was able to upvote multiple times I would. Could you further explain the sorting logic though?

Comment: @P.b the sort will sort the 2 column array returned by the choose first on column 2(2) Descending(-1), then it will sort on column 1(1) ascending(1).  The two arrays in the 2nd and 3rd criteria work together to determine order of sort and method.

Comment: Oh, of course. I thought of it as sorting `unq` and the countif result separately, but they're joined by choose as one array/range. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but after searching for an answer to this, I managed to come up with my own solution that I think may be simpler.

I used nested Textjoin and Textsplit and then took Unique values of the resultant array.  And sorted for good measure.  In cell E1

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:C2),,";")))
```

Then in cell F1 I used a Countif on the spill range from E1

```
=COUNTIF(A1:C2,E1#)
```